# Extract lines that have a specific ending and use those to extract from another file

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I have two files, both of which I need to extract things from. The first file contains a barcoded line and ends with an OTU number. I need to extract lines that have specific OTU numbers.

Once I have the file of extracted lines, then I need to extract lines from my next file that match the barcodes from the first file.

For example, let's say I want to extract all of the lines that contain OTU_1 from this file [image]

There are unique barcodes associated with each line that contains OTU 1, in this example there are 5 shown:

> ```
> 907.2::M02542:207:000000000-AWDAH:1:1115:18838:201661:N:0:GTGAAA
> 905.2::M02542:207:000000000-AWDAH:1:1101:24324:103291:N:0:GTGAAA
> 1205.2::M02542:207:000000000-AWDAH:1:2115:22195:238121:N:0:GTGAAA
> 906.2::M02542:207:000000000-AWDAH:1:1115:24086:126561:N:0:GTGAAA
> 910.2::M02542:207:000000000-AWDAH:1:1112:26236:215801:N:0:GTGAAA
> ```

I will need to use these barcodes to extract sequences from my next file:

[image]

As you can see, the barcodes start after > and I will need all of the information between the > (i.e. my sequences).

I have tried the obvious thing, which would be to use a spreadsheet type of software and sort by OTU #, but my files are too big (~ several billion lines long).

Comment: HI, How you were able to add pictures with 1 rep!! But could you please post the actual text instead of in snapshot?

Comment: @AFSHIN: That restriction on new users [applies only to Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, and Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111388/271976#195927) — at least for the past four years.

Comment: @Mara Cloutier: (1) AFSHIN is right; [we really prefer that you post text ***as text***.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/80216) (2) Most of use aren’t geneticists (or whatever you are), so we aren’t familiar with your file formats.  You say “I will need all of the information between the `>` (i.e., my sequences),” and you *show* a file where (exactly) every other line begins with `>`.  Is this true in general?  Do barcode lines in the second file always appear in pairs?  You should address information like this in your question.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Some barcodes appear multiple times.  Do you want every occurrence? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete (including actual sample text, if at all possible).

Answer (score 1):

With *GNU* `grep`, something like this should work:

```
grep -o '\S\+\s\+OTU_1$' Fasta.readmap.uc | \
grep -o '^\S\+' | \
grep -f - -A 1 092016MABits-pr.fasta | \
grep -v '^>'
```

The `-o` makes `grep` output only the matching text.  The `-f -` tells `grep` to search for the patterns piped in from *STDIN*.  The `-A 1` tells `grep` to show the line after the match.  The final `grep` only matches lines that don't being with a "*>*".

Comment: I think the last `grep` is missing option `-A 1` to include the lines with the sequences

Comment: @Philippos, Perhaps so.  My assumption is that whatever text editor the OP used for those snapshots had *word wrap* turned on.

Comment: I doubt that because (1) he wrote we wants to extract "information between the >", (2) the screenshot shows a scrollbar indicating no need to wrap and (3) AFAIK this [fasta format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) carries the sequences after the `>` lines.

Comment: @Philippos: I believe that you are *mostly* right — the second file has two-line records, so the `grep` needs `-A 1`.  But the first file appears to be line-wrapped, and I don’t see a scroll bar in either image.  (The orange bar at the top of the second image appears (to me) to be a *progress* bar.)

Comment: @agc: I appreciate the appreciation, but you're thanking the wrong person: Philippos is the one who posted the Wikipedia link.

Comment: @Philippos, Thanks. I'm not familiar with typical fasta formats, and that WP entry cleared things up. Revised answer.